# Entropy of random variable which denotes the number of heads landed after 3 coin flips

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I am not sure how to work this out but I split the outcomes of 3 coin flips into the 8 possible outcomes: HHH, HHT, HTH, HTT | TTT, TTH, THT, THH

And have gotten a probability mass function for the random variable out of the 3 flips(only 1 head is 1/4, only 2 heads is 3/8, only 3 heads is 1/8) -

I have calculated the entropy as $H(x) = -sum(P(xi)*logP(xi)) =-1/4*log(1/4)-3/8*log(3/8)-1/8*log(1/8)$ - is that method correct?

Comment: The probability of only 1 head is wrong. You should also consider the probability of the event of zero heads.

Comment: true. hadn't thought of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is right, except that you did not compute the correct mass function reflecting the random variable of interest. For more on entropy, this is a [lecture were i explain the intuition behind it](https://youtu.be/mdJYfPqiwTM).

Let $X$ be the random variable denoting the number of heads in your experiment 
\begin{align}
 p_0  \triangleq \Pr(X = 0) &= \Pr(TTT) = \frac{1}{8}\\
 p_1  \triangleq\Pr(X = 1) &= \Pr(HTT) +\Pr(THT)+\Pr(TTH)  = \frac{3}{8}\\
 p_2  \triangleq\Pr(X = 2) &= \Pr(HHT) +\Pr(HTH)+\Pr(THH)  = \frac{3}{8}\\
 p_3  \triangleq\Pr(X = 3) &= \Pr(HHH)   = \frac{1}{8}
\end{align}
This is a mass function because $\sum p_i = 1$, in contrast to yours which is not. Now, we can easily compute the entropy
$$H(X) = - \sum p_i \log p_i$$